# How two plot two histograms together in R from two different datasets

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two different datasets, both with the same variables. I want to plot the variable `Age` against its density from both datasets in a histogram and overlay it for comparison using `ggplot2`.

Any clues?

Comment: Try something that gets you close and ask for help. Do not ask someone to do it for you.

Answer (score -1):

I just solved my question. Take a look!

`plot1 <- ggplot() + 
geom_histogram(aes(x=df1$Age, y=..density..),  fill="lightblue") + geom_histogram(aes(x=df2$Age, y=..density..),  fill="darkblue")`